# In Appium find an Android view by a unique id that isn't the view's id field

Tags: android, android-layout, appium

I've created an Android app where I have programmatically created a number of controls such as radio buttons, up and down buttons, etc.  These views have ids in their `id` field that are not unique and I cannot make unique.  I want to be able to reliably locate these elements for the sake of automated testing using Appium.

I had hoped I could put a unique id in the `tag` field of these views (as this is an appropriate use of a view's `tag` field) to solve this problem, but it seems that Appium cannot (or will not) use the `tag` field for identification purposes.

A solution that is working is to put the unique id in the view's `content-desc` field.  The Appium method `findElementById()` will successfully find the element that way.  But this is a misuse of `content-desc` as it is intended to be used to describe the view in a way that is useful for accessibility purposes.

Since the controls are created programmatically and their order is not guaranteed, so I don't want to find the elements by index.

Is there a way to include a unique id in an Android view that Appium can find that isn't a view's `content-desc` field?

Answer (score 1):

As of 12/19/2016, Appium doesn't support finding views by Tag. We're going to be looking into that soon, however. Keep an eye on https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6025.

You're right that the current workaround is to set the content-desc.